# how can i update Jenkins without lose the previous work?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries

i use the shared library in my pipeline, but now, it does not work. When I open the Manage Jenkins the following message appear:

The following installed plugins are deprecated:

- [WMI Windows Agents Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-slaves/)
- [Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps-global-lib/)

In general, this means that these plugins are either obsolete, no longer being developed, or may no longer work.

See the linked web pages for further information about the cause for the deprecation, and suggestions on how to proceed.

How can I update my Jenkins without lose the previous items.

New version of Jenkins (2.361.4) is available for download ([changelog](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/)).

I want to make my shared library work again; thank you very much to any one try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the links (which I added for you), it says:

**WMI Windows Agents**

> NOTICE OF DEPRECATION (May 2023)
>
> This plugin will be deprecated in May of 2023. SSH is now a very
> viable, secure and robust solution for connecting to Windows based
> agents using native Windows binaries for [OpenSSH Server](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) or another
> method such as [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). There is also the [Windows Cloud plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-cloud/) for
> Jenkins which uses WinRM, a more modern remote management solution.

Fore reference, this is the Unix [SSH Build Agents](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-slaves/) plugin.

**Pipeline: Deprecated Groovy Libraries**

> This plugin is deprecated. It implements a legacy mode of defining
> Groovy libraries in which there is a single Git repository hosted by
> Jenkins itself, to which you may push changes. Instead use [Pipeline:
> Groovy Libraries](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-groovy-lib/).

It seems the guidance you seek is provided in the links you referred. You don't mention what you are upgrading from, but in all cases, closely read the [LTS Upgrade Guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/), take a backup before upgrading, verify on a non-production instance, check the logs on startup for issues and validate after upgrading.

The WMI Agents is Notice of Deprecation, so you are safe for the next 6 months or so, giving you time to move to connecting your agents via SSH. You may already have [SSH installed on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui). For Windows, the default installation folder is %systemdrive%\Windows\System32\openssh

Pipeline: Groovy Libraries has Comprehensive user documentation can be found in the [Pipeline chapter of the User Handbook](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).